# Gulp error when creating sourcemap ("CssSyntaxError")

Tags: sass, gulp, source-maps

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm getting a really odd error message when I try and create a sourcemap file using Gulp.

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
CssSyntaxError: /www/static/sass/maps/main.css.map:1:198: Missed semicolon
```

I want them to be created in a separate .map file. I cannot understand why it's telling me there's an error in the file I've asked it to create...?

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    input = 'static/sass/**/*.scss',
    output = 'static/css';

var sassOptions = {
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
};

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(input)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(input, ['sass']);
});

// Default task - Compile then set Watch
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Why are you placing your source maps onto the production server at all?

Comment: @cimmanon I'm not placing my sourcemaps on any production server. What gave you that idea?

Comment: You did:  "I want them to be created in a separate .map file so the average user won't see them when visiting the site".  Why would the average user see the source map at all, unless it was on the production server?

Comment: @cimmanon By default the sourcemap is included inline within the CSS. I just want to separate it so I don't have to modify my gulpfile and recompile (for a sourcemap-less version) before every deployment.

Comment: @cimmanon I've removed the confusing sentence for you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It turns out it was simply the placement of the line `.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))`. Moving it solved the problem:

```
return gulp
    .src(input)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // This line moved to here
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
```

Would love to know why :-/

Comment: same here, but no idea why the sourcemaps need to be in the end

Comment: @Jorre I believe sourcemaps.write() needs to come after autoprefixer() because autoprefixer attempts to add prefixes to the source map, which causes the error

Comment: @EddieHong Ah! Thank you for explaining that! It makes perfect sense.

Comment: Can you explain why sourcemaps.write needs to be at the end?